# Retrieving checkbox status in an HTML table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remember the syntax for getting an element inside a table using JavaScript. I have a table with a checkbox in it. These are dynamic checkboxes or i would just use the getElementById. Here is how I'm doing it. I know I'm close, but just figured it out yet. Here is the code I have so far:

```
   table_name.rows[0].cells[0].item[0]
```

or

```
   tbl_run_avail.rows[1].cells[0].elements[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using DOM Level 0, you're probably looking for the [childNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.childNodes) property:

```
table_name.rows[0].cells[0].childNodes[0];
```

The above assumes that the check box is the very first child node of your table cell. In this situation, you can avoid unnecessary indexing by using the [firstChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.firstChild) property:

```
table_name.rows[0].cells[0].firstChild;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy if you use the `children` property:

```
yourTable.rows[0].cells[0].children[0];
```